# can't able to convert axmschart as bitmap.(vb.net)

Tags: crystal-reports, vb.net-2010, vb6-migration

i am working on a project which is migrated from vb6 to vb.net.And during working with the crystal reports i got this problem.Actually i have to print the axmschart of my application in reports.So i am using the following code :

```
  gtmpString = Application.StartupPath & gsGraphPicPath

    Dim myPic As New Bitmap(_chtAnlysGraph_0.AsBitmap)'''''ERROR here...as bitmap is                   not a member of AXMSCHART''''''''
    PictureBox1.Image = myPic
    PictureBox1.Image.Save(gtmpString, System.Drawing.Imaging.ImageFormat.Png)

    Dim intCount As Short
    Dim dRow As DataRow
    Dim dTable As New DataTable
    Dim dt As New DataSetResults.AnalysisTableDataTable 'Report filling 

    dTable = dt.Copy
    dRow = dTable.NewRow
    For intCount = 1 To msgAnlysData.Rows - 1
        dRow = dTable.NewRow
        dRow.Item("Sr_No") = msgAnlysData.get_TextMatrix(intCount, 1)
        dRow.Item("abs_val") = msgAnlysData.get_TextMatrix(intCount, 2)
        dRow.Item("pt_conc") = msgAnlysData.get_TextMatrix(intCount, 3)
        dRow.Item("lin_conc") = msgAnlysData.get_TextMatrix(intCount, 4)
        dRow.Item("poly_conc") = msgAnlysData.get_TextMatrix(intCount, 5)
        'If gtmpString = True Then
        gtmpString = Application.StartupPath & gsGraphPicPath
        dRow.Item("graph1") = savepic(gtmpString)
        ' End If
        If msgAnlysData.get_TextMatrix(intCount, 2) = Nothing Then

        Else
            dTable.Rows.Add(dRow)
        End If
    Next intCount
```

Help me out here plzz.

Answer (score 0):

```
Dim myPic As New Bitmap(_chtAnlysGraph_0)
```